# How to apply a NSG to an existing subnet using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am creating new NSG with ARM template and updating the subnets at the same ARM template. I would like to be able to get subnets addressprefix with "reference" but when doing so I always get the circular dependency detected. Is there any way around it? My subnet arm template section looks like this:

```
      {
        "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "[reference(resourceId(variables('ResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName')), '2018-03-01').addressPrefix]",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('NSGName'))]"
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: if you remove the address prefix line from your code it should be fine, in the deployment it wont update the address prefix

Comment: Afaik the address prefix line is mandatory when updating the subnet to use the specified NSG?

Comment: have you tried ? it is not mark as required in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/subnets. Btw I am not sure if it is working

Comment: Yes I have tried. "Error: Code=AddressPrefixStringCannotBeNullOrEmpty; Message=Address prefix string for resource /subscriptions/snipped/subnets/subnet cannot be null or empty."

Comment: Ok the solution was to use a link/nested template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link on how to apply a NSG to an existing subnet:

[Apply a NSG to an existing subnet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-nsg-add-to-existing-subnet/)

This template uses a link template to workaround the circular reference but you can also use a nested template to do the same in the same ARM template (see [Using linked and nested templates when deploying Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates))

Here is an ARM template that do the same using a nested template:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the existing VNet"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "default",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the existing subnet."
      }
    },
    "nsgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the new nsg."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[parameters('nsgName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "properties": {

      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
      "name": "apply-nsg-to-subnet",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('nsgName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "[reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName')), '2018-03-01').addressPrefix]",
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('nsgName'))]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```